# Remove the "Customize Quick Access Toolbar" button

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm working on a project where we want to have a quick access bar that is unchangeable/static.  We've looked at inheriting from the CMFCQuickAccessToolbar and removing that button, but those attempts seem fruitless. Just getting rid of the button completely gets rid of the toolbar. Anyone have some experience with this, or an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of headache we found that there was no clean solution to removing just that button from the toolbar. Instead, we opted to place the buttons we wanted to display in the quickaccess bar in the tabs group. These button will appear on the right side (beside the help icon in word). To replicate the look of the QA buttons, I had to create an imagelist and load our buttons into it.

```
CImageList theList;
CBitmap bm;
bm.LoadBitmap( IDB_QASMALL );
theList.Create(16,16, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 5, 0);
theList.Add(&bm, RGB(192,192,192));
```

I then created ribbonButtons to be added to the tabs group, with the proper command IDs, empty text, and the proper icon from my image list.

```
CMFCRibbonButton* button = new CMFCRibbonButton( ID_SOMECOMMAND, _T("\na"), theList.ExtractIcon(<IconOffset>));
m_wndRibbonBar.AddToTabs(mp);
```

It's not a perfect solution, but it at least gives us a similar UI without the worry of getting rid of that stupid customize button. You also have the freedom to use labels on your buttons.